# select an attribute with max date attribute

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath, clob

I am parsing an XML clob in oracle and I have a situation where there is a multi-item sequence like this:

```
 <ns2:UserID dateTime="2016-02-10T17:25:02.435-05:00" name="Indi Psit" note="review" userType="CompletedBy" />
           <ns2:UserID dateTime="2016-02-10T17:25:02.501-05:00" name="Indi Psit" note="review" userType="InProgressBy" />
           <ns2:UserID dateTime="2016-02-10T17:31:18.379-05:00" name="Indi Psit" note="accept" userType="ActionBy" />
```

I can get the max(dateTime) from this sequence by doing:

```
 OfferUpdateDate                     varchar2(30) PATH'max(/off:Users/typ:UserID/@dateTime/xs:dateTime(.))'
```

But I want to also get "name" attribute from UserID element, where dateTime=max(dateTime) from the sequence. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible XPath to get `name` attribute of `UserID` element where `dateTime` attribute equals maximum `dateTime` (wrapped for readability) :

```
/off:Users/typ:UserID[
    @dateTime/xs:dateTime(.) eq max(/off:Users/typ:UserID/@dateTime/xs:dateTime(.))
]/@name
```

Comment: I get the following error with this:
ORA-31013: Invalid XPATH expression
31013. 00000 -  "Invalid XPATH expression"
*Cause:    XPATH expression passed to the function is invalid.
*Action:   Check the xpath expression for possible syntax errors.